# Does $P=NP$ require an algorithm that uses polynomial space?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity, big-o-notation, p-vs-np

if there was an algorithm that runs in polynomial time, but its size requires $O(2^n)$ bits, would that still prove $P=NP$?

Answer (score 2):

You can think about this more informally: it takes time to access memory. For any algorithm, whether a Turing machine or using some other formalism, whenever it queries or modifies memory that takes a certain amount of time. Therefore, total space used by an algorithm (units of space accessed during execution) is always **less than or equal to** the time used by the algorithm:
$$
\textsf{space} \le \text{time}
$$

For this reason, as nir explains, the algorithm you envision cannot exist.

Comment: Thanks man. Looks like I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

Any turing machine with running time $O(T(n))$ for some function $T$, will have to use at most $O(T(n))$ cells on the tape, and hence will use at most $O(T(n))$ space.

Therefore, the answer is that such an algorithm wouldn't even exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I wonder if this is really true. Could you please elaborate a bit more or link a source for how you came to this conclusion?

Comment: Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity#Relationships_between_classes It says that $DTIME(t)\subseteq DSPACE(t)$, and therefore if you solve something with time $t$, it is also solved with space $t$. Hence - if you were to solve something with a polynomial time - it will also require only polynomial space.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it.